# Is it possible to make a connection to an SFTP repository with no additional libraries?

Tags: java, jsp, sftp

Is it possible to make a connection to an SFTP repository with no additional libraries? It's important, that no further libraries are used to connect to the repository as I'm not "allowed" to use them. If it's not possible I'll have to live with it.

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, you can implement this from scratch using the networking features that are part of the JRE. The question is: Do you consider this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Cheers. How much code/time will it need/ take? Just a guess...

Comment: Thats how those libraries were written :)

Comment: As you said it's probably not worth it. I only need it for a jsp file that retrieves the paths of some files in the mentioned repository.

Comment: I'm guessing 8 years 3 months and 5 days.

Comment: O.o Haha, well don't think that'd be efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running on a platform that has `ssh` installed you could invoke command line processes using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) methods to perform whatever operations you need.

Agricultural I know, but probably pragmatic given the OP's circumstances.